# Carry out ongoing, branching conversation with Discord bot

Tags: python, discord.py

With `discord.py` asynchronous/ dynamic functionality, how do I achieve running in a more rail-like manner as a normal console app would work? The way I see it now, getting the `on_message` event does not allow for a tree-like structure in a response line like a chatbot. Below is a small example of what I am looking to do. The problem is that I need a way to get the `on_message` and run it only within the `stepOne()` once it has been called.

```
async def stepOne()
  await message.channel.send("How are you")
  await asyncio.sleep(6)
  if  msg == "good":
    await message.channel.send("Happy to hear it")
  
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  msg = message.content

  if  msg == "Hi":
    await message.channel.send("Hello")
    await stepOne()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting question! In order to do this, you're going to have to store state about where in the conversation you currently are, when the last message was sent, and presumably which user you're talking to. In order to more tidily encapsulate this state data, I'm going to switch from the `@client.event` decorator form to the more traditional OOP style, defining event listeners as methods of a class that inherits from `Client`.

```
from datetime import timedelta
import discord

# This is just to store these in a different file and not show them
# publicly.
from tokens import TOKEN, CHANNEL_ID

class ConversationBot(discord.Client):
    def __init__(self, channel_id, start_node, max_wait=6):
        super().__init__()
        self.channel_id = channel_id
        self.start_node = start_node
        # Store the max wait as a timedelta for easier comparison.
        self.max_wait = timedelta(seconds=max_wait)
        self.reset()
        
    def reset(self):
        """Prepare for a new conversation."""
        self.current_node = self.start_node
        self.current_talker = None
        self.last_message_time = None

    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Ready')

    async def on_message(self, message):
        if (message.author == self.user or
            message.channel.id != self.channel_id):
            # Abort if the message was sent by this bot, or isn't in the
            # right channel.
            return

        if self.current_node is not self.start_node:
            # Things that behave differently if we're already in a
            # conversation

            if message.created_at - self.last_message_time > self.max_wait:
                # If it's been too long, reset the bot--but then make
                # sure to call on_message again, in case this message
                # should start a new conversation.
                self.reset()
                await self.on_message(message)
                return

            if message.author != self.current_talker:
                # Only listen to the person we're already talking to.
                return

        # Get the destination corresponding to the message, if there is
        # one.
        destination = self.current_node.get_destination(message.content)
        if destination:
            # Send the bot's next message
            channel = await self.fetch_channel(self.channel_id)
            await channel.send(destination.message)
            
            # Store the new node and update data. Or, if there's nowhere
            # further it can go from there, just reset.
            if destination.destinations:
                self.current_talker = message.author
                self.last_message_time = message.created_at
                self.current_node = destination
            else:
                self.reset()


class Node:
    """Represents a point in a conversation"""
    def __init__(self, message):
        self.message = message
        self.destinations = {}

    def add_destination(self, message, node):
        """Add a possible next node, and the message that triggers it"""
        self.destinations[message] = node

    def get_destination(self, message_text):
        """Get a node corresponding to a message (or None)"""
        return self.destinations.get(message_text)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Define the nodes in our conversation
    start = Node('')
    how_are_you = Node('Hello\nHow are you?')
    happy = Node('Happy to hear it')
    sorry = Node('Sorry to hear that')

    # Connect them to each other
    start.add_destination('Hi', how_are_you)
    how_are_you.add_destination('Good', happy)
    how_are_you.add_destination('Not great', sorry)

    bot = ConversationBot(CHANNEL_ID, start)
    bot.run(TOKEN)
```

This structure is flexible, and can contain complex branching (or even looping) pathways if you like.

Note that I've made it listen only to a specific channel. If you want to listen to multiple channels (and potentially be involved in multiple conversations at once), just keep in mind you'll want to track them separately.

There are certainly things that could be improved and added—making the responses case-insensitive comes to mind—but hopefully this is a helpful starting point. (Past a certain point of complexity, it would probably be worth it to put together a way to define conversation nodes in something like JSON or YAML instead of directly in your Python code.)